# When loading an NSManagedObject from Core Data, do I get it's children for free?

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship, nsmanagedobject, entities

I'm attempting to learn how to use this fancy new pattern of Relationships in Core Data to emulate a String array. I have an Alarm entity and a NotificationUuid entity. Alarm is NotificationUuid's parent entity, because an Alarm can have many NotificationUuids, and a NotificationUuid can only have one parent Alarm. I have all this set up in my .xcdatamodeld file.

My question is this: When I fetch the parent Alarm object like this:

```
private func loadAlarms() {

    os_log("loadAlarms() called", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<AlarmMO>(entityName: "Alarm")

    do {
        if self.alarms.count == 0 {
            self.alarms = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            os_log("Loading %d alarms", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug, self.alarms.count)
        } else {
            os_log("Didn't need to load alarms", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch alarms. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

do I get the AlarmMO (Alarm Managed Object) object's children, the NotificationUuid objects, for free? Or do I now have to set up a fetch request for them too? How does this whole fancy parent/child relationship work, and how do I set/load stuff from these entities?

Thanks

Here's how I've defined AlarmMO:

```
import CoreData

@objc(AlarmMO)
public class AlarmMO: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var alarmNumber: Int64
    @NSManaged public var alarmTime: NSDate?
    @NSManaged public var endTimeInterval: Double
    @NSManaged public var recurrence: Int64
    @NSManaged public var startTimeInterval: Double
    @NSManaged public var notificationUuidChildren: NSSet?


}

// MARK: Generated accessors for notificationUuidChildren
extension AlarmMO {

    @objc(addNotificationUuidChildrenObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToNotificationUuidChildren(_ value: NotificationUuidMO)

    @objc(removeNotificationUuidChildrenObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromNotificationUuidChildren(_ value: NotificationUuidMO)

    @objc(addNotificationUuidChildren:)
    @NSManaged public func addToNotificationUuidChildren(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeNotificationUuidChildren:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromNotificationUuidChildren(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

and NotificationUuidMO:

```
import CoreData

@objc(NotificationUuid)
public class NotificationUuidMO: AlarmMO {

    @NSManaged public var notificationUuid: String
    @NSManaged public var alarmParent: AlarmMO

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When seeing your `AlarmMO` model, you can just fetch your `AlarmMO` model which will hold the list of `NotificationUuidMO` in `notificationUuidChildren` Set. So there is no need to fetch `NotificationUuidMO` separately.

And AlarmMO to `NotificationUuidMO` is one to many relationship. So you can get `notificationUuidChildren` from `AlarmMO` and `alarmParent` from `NotificationUuidMO`.

To add `NotificationUuidMO` to `notificationUuidChildren` Set, you can use Core-Data generated accessors given in `extension AlarmMO`.

Example:

```
let notificationUuid = NotificationUuidMO....
let alarmMO = AlarmMO....

alarmMO.addToNotificationUuidChildren(notificationUuid)//Here your notificationUuid will be added to `notificationUuidChildren` Set and `alarmParent` of your `notificationUuid` will be automatically assigned to `alarmMO`.
```